# Compare 2D array with some logic, can't think of it

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

```
//2D array with row4 and column4


11  12  18  40
14  15  13  22
11  17  19  23
17  14  20  28
```

My question is how do i looping the idea like this
. When looping for [0][0] = 11.
for the same entire rows which is 12 , 18 , 40 and same entire column 14 , 11 , 17 cannot be count.going through, After that my second looping will just looping the table sample like this

```
**11**  **12**  **18**  **40**
**14**    15      13      22
**11**    17      19      23
**17**    14      20      28
```

my looping just can read those number without ** .
for second time. will choose the second column, which number is smallest and store into a variable temporaryA , and third looping will choose third column, choose smallest value and store into temporaryB, and fourth looping will choose fourth column and store into temporaryC

Finally. My answer will be the first number i choose just now 
ANswer = 11 + temporaryA + temporaryB +temporaryC

void BranchandBound( int **minimumCost , int p , int j ){

```
/*
11  12  18  40
14  15  13  22
11  17  19  23
17  14  20  28
*/
bool *stars = new bool[4];
int totalMin = 0;
for( int y = 0 ; y < p ; y++ ){
    int min,iMin = -1;
        for( int x = 0 ; x < j ; x++ ){
        if( !stars[y] || (iMin < 0 || min > minimumCost[y][x]) ){
            min = minimumCost[y][x];
            cout << "minimum : " << min << endl;
            iMin = min;
            totalMin += min;
        }
        stars[iMin] = 1;
    }
}

cout << "Total : " << totalMin << endl;
```

}

Comment: Can you trash the original array?

Comment: what you mean that trash?

Comment: Modify the array, so you have the result, but the array didn't retain the original content.

Comment: so you mean i have to store into another temp array variable isn't? can you provide simple code to let me have a look on it?

Comment: Are you trying to say, you can't loop in that 2D array? the numbers with label `**` is the only value you can access?

Comment: the ** is mean the value i cant access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to exclude columns where the minimum was (marked with stars in your question). Let's just remember them:

```
bool stars[4] = { 0 };
```

Now find the minimum as usual...

```
for (int y = 0; y < sz; y++) {
    int min, iMin = -1;
    for (int x = 0; x < sz; x++) {
```

Here, we have to skip columns where minimum already was:

```
        if (!stars[x] && (iMin < 0 || min > numbers[x][y])) {
            min = numbers[x][y];
            iMin = x;
        }
```

And now remember where the next minimum came from:

```
        stars[iMin] = 1;
    }
}
```

Done! Summing all the `min` is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: can u tell me for your third coding. should be iMin = min ?

Comment: i tried your coding. but my answer should be 61 , as 11 + 15 + 13 + 22. but yours answer i get is more than this..

Comment: iMin is the index of the minimal element. Now how did you get 15 and 22 when the minimum in the second row is 13?

Comment: i want to count it based on column . yours 1 isnt is row?

for example. the second column compare value 15 , 17 and 14 , and the store the 14, not 15 sorry , after that the third looping is check the third column 13 , 19 , 20 , store the 13 in minimum , and then last looping will compare the 22 , 23 , 28 , then store the 22 .

Comment: Swap `x` and `y` then. And it should be 11 + 14 + 13 + 23, 22 is taken too.

Comment: but why 23 is taken also ? i just want to add 11 + 14 + 13 + 22 4 number only. but why 5 number is taken .. and like just now i ask u . isn't should be iMin = min ? because when i print out the stars[] , it show me 1 value, i don't know what is that for

Comment: after i swap x and y with all. the value i get become 0 . nothing compare , maybe the value iMin = i there wrong?

Comment: `iMin` is the element index (minimum `i`), not the minimum itself! `stars` should also be initialized...

Comment: but i keep repeating and see your function, it doesn't have the variable i .. you mean stars just to initialized to be NULL VALUE ? so what should i change it?

Comment: `i` is `x`. Also changed the array initialization.

Comment: i changed it . but not really know what you mean by array initialization for boolean. just initialize the bool at outside right? it doesn't related inside the looping . correct ? and the answer i get is 80 , it printed out 6 minimum value . 11 14 13 11 17 14 and total is 60 . but my answer would be 11 14 13 22 answer = 60

Comment: Please don't take this example literally, and try to implement the algorithm yourself.

Comment: i having problem and think too much for this. i trying to but i keep fail. thats why i asking question and hope people can answer me.